# Two convergent subsequences and their limits

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$\{a_n\}$ is a sequence. I'm asked to verify the following statement: "If $\{a_{2n}\}$ and $\{a_{3n}\}$ converge then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{2n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{3n}$$

I think this is not true, but I simply can't think of a decent counterexample. I tried constructing a divergent sequence by assigning different values to $a_n$ based on $n$. But it seems like $a_{2n}$ and $a_{3n}$ "overlap" a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's true, for $\{a_{6n}\}$ is a subseqeunce of $\{a_{2n}\}$ ($a_{6n} = a_{2(3n)}$) and a subseqeunce of $\{a_{3n}\}$ ($a_{6n} = a_{3(2n)}$). Thus

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_{2n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} a_{6n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} a_{3n}.$$

Comment: Wow, how could I miss that. Thank you. I'll accept your answer as soon as the system allows me to do so. By the way, when I was working on this problem, I thought about this statement: "$\{a_n\}$ converge iff $\{a_{2n}\}$,$\{a_{3n}\}$ and $\{a_{2n-1}\}$ converge". Do you think it is true?

Comment: Yes, that statement is also true. The main issue is the reverse direction. Suppose those subsequences converge. Since $\{a_{2n}\}$ and $\{a_{3n}\}$ converge, they have the same limit. Since $\{a_{6n-2}\}$ is a subsequence of $\{a_{3n}\}$ (since $a_{6n-3} = a_{3(2n-1)}$) and a subsequence of $\{a_{2n-1}\}$ (since $a_{6n-3} = a_{2(3n-1)-1}$), the subsequenes $\{a_{3n}\}$ and $\{a_{2n-1}\}$ have the same limit. Thus $\{a_{2n}\}$ and $\{a_{2n-1}\}$ have the same limit, which implies $\{a_n\}$ converges.

Comment: let me verify the last part - "If $\{a_{2n}\}$ and $\{a_{2n-1}\}$ have the same limit then $\{a_{n}\}$ converges". Is it true because $\{2n\} \cup\{2n+1\}=\mathbb{N}$? Thank you!

Comment: That's essentially the reason, but it takes a little more work to actually prove it.

Answer (score 2):

This is true because if $(a_{2n})$ and $(a_{3n})$ are convergent then all their subsequences converge to the same limit. In particular consider the sequence $(a_{6n})$. Then $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}a_{2n}=\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}a_{6n} =\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}a_{3n}$.